# DevicePolicyManager resetPassword not working some times

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

All, 
I am having a very strange issue.
I have the following code that enables and disables the PIN based on certain conditions

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;
mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(context, DeviceAdminSampleReceiver.class);

public void disablePINLock(DBHelper myDBHelper, Context context) {

    mDPM.setPasswordQuality(mDeviceAdminSample,
            DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED);
    mDPM.setPasswordMinimumLength(mDeviceAdminSample, 0);
    boolean result = false;
    result = mDPM.resetPassword("", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);

    if (result) {
        // Toast: "Successfully Disabled PIN lock"
    }
    else {
        // Toast: "Could not disable PIN lock"
    }
}

public void enablePINLock(DBHelper myDBHelper, Context context) {
    mDPM.setPasswordQuality(mDeviceAdminSample,
            DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC);
    mDPM.setPasswordMinimumLength(mDeviceAdminSample, 4);

    Cursor c = myDBHelper.getSetting("'random'");
    if (c != null) {
        boolean result = mDPM.resetPassword("1234",
                DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
        if (result) {
            // Toast: "Successfully Enabled PIN lock"
        }
        else {
            // Toast: "Could not enable PIN lock"
        }
    }
    else {
        // Toast: "Could not enable PIN lock"
        c.close();
    }
}
```

The code was working fine until a few days ago. I restarted the phone to finish updating and since then the `disablePINLock` function is not working correctly. When the function executes all I get is 
"result" is false and toast message "Could not disable PIN". The `enablePINLock` method is working just fine and has always worked fine.

Since the restart `result = mDPM.resetPassword("", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);` has failed to execute. I tried to catch an exception but it didn't help.

At this point I am clueless as to why the method stopped working after the restart. I checked the device administrators, enabled/disabled the app few times without any success.

Also I am not sure if this is related, but let me say this. The device administrator screen has my app always checked, even after I uncheck the app and deactivate it, the app name has the box checked.

Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: you phone is rooted right?are u applying in AndroidL?

Comment: Yes, the phone is rooted and I use custom ROM, android revolution with 4.4.3. I am using Android 4.0 ICS in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've "checked the device administrators" but you don't say what you saw there. Are there any other active device administrators on the device? `DevicePolicyManager.resetPassword()` will return false if the password you provide is not compliant with the aggregate of password policies set by *all* device admins. It sounds like perhaps another device admin is still active.

Also, with regard to your last point:

> The device administrator screen has my app always checked, even after I uncheck the app and deactivate it, the app name has the box checked.

That's a common bug with the Device Administrators screen: the checkbox often stays on even when you've successfully disabled an admin. Try backing out of the Device Administrators screen then going back in. It should be unchecked now.